# Why am I seeing the Savage!, Elusive!, and Baroque! Qualities?

Tags: fallen-london

I've noticed that I recently gained a few new Qualities, namely Savage!, Elusive!, and Baroque!:

[image: SAVAGE! 90 ELUSIVE! 90 BAROQUE! 90]

It seems that these Qualities are part of the forbidden game of Knife-and-Candle, but I haven't put myself so in harm's way as to gain admittance to this dark sport.

I also have another picture to show how perplexing this situation is to me:

[image: Not a participant in Knife-and-Candle]

**If I am not a player in the game of Knife-and-Candle, why am I seeing these Qualities?**

Comment: I have to ask the obvious question: do you have any Iron Knife Tokens in your inventory?

Comment: @PaulMarshall The only Iron Knife Token I ever had I gave away long before any of these Qualities appeared. I'm also an umpire in the game, but I also started that long before these Qualities appeared.

Comment: There have been some new changes rolled out over the past few days, and I've seen a few other buglets - such as getting my Earnest of Payment two days in a row. This could simply be another bug.

Comment: That would make sense, yes.

Comment: I would speculate that, although you gave away the token before the addition of the content, your save is still internally marked as having had one. Probably a bug, but this is sometimes a device used to advertise a certain feature. Ideally, the player would notice the new content, and in curiosity explore the feature that might otherwise get ignored.

Answer (score 1):

A (very!) late response: I've found that, when you go on a zee-voyage, it clears a large number of progress qualities. This includes SAVAGE!, ELUSIVE!, and BAROQUE!.

If this problem happens again, and you have access to a zee-vessel, go on a cruise and it should clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not in Knife-and-Candle, but these qualities are showing up, it's a bug in the game. Writing to support@failbettergames.com with your character name and an explanation of the bug will generally get it cleared up in short order.